# Mismatched User Environment (Sandbox) OneSignal Cordova

Tags: cordova, xcode8, onesignal

I want send a notification by OneSignal, I follow all steps in the document but always I show this message 'Apple returned a BadDeviceToken error. Some users are tied to a different environment from your sending environment.' Any idea!!

(Production Certificate) Bundle ID: ***** , Expires: September 15, 2018

(Sandbox Certificate) Bundle ID: ***** , Expires: September 15, 2018

Mismatched User Environment (Sandbox) Apple returned a BadDeviceToken error. Some users are tied to a different environment from your sending environment.

This warning occurred 1 time, last occurring less than 10 seconds ago.

Affected users: 6414cbae-876a-4360-9783-eb51c0cc0e29

Help me to fix this.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I ran into the same issue

Comment: same problem here.. how to fix this?

Answer (score 16):

If you are running iOS 12, with xCode 10, then you need to go to `File -> Workspace Settings...`

Change the *build System:* to **Legacy Build System**.

Save and build

Comment: Actually it's a solution that is working just fine with me and I kept surfing the internet for hours and this is the only option that worked for me

Comment: I already found best solution, you must create and download distribution certificate  with push notification also with current bundle of your application.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. Had this problem with a Cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you re-sent your p12 file to the OneSignal server.
I also meet this issue and solve it by opening another project on the OneSignal server.
The p12 file might be in catch for some reason I guess.